# Can we pass a callback function to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am more of a JS guy and I need to resolve a issue related to Android(React Native) where in I need to pass and get the callback function to the following Java interface -

com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray

https://appdoc.app/artifact/cn.ransj.rn/react-native/0.38.c/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableArray.html

Here is the JAVA code from the library -

```
@Override
    public void receiveCommand(SketchCanvas view, int commandType, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
        switch (commandType)
            // Other casses
            case COMMAND_TRANSFER_BASE64: {
                view.getBase64(args.getString(0), args.getBoolean(1), args.getBoolean(2), args.getBoolean(3), args.getBoolean(4), **args.getJSModule(5)**);
                return;
            }
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                        "Unsupported command %d received by %s.",
                        commandType,
                        getClass().getSimpleName()));
        }
    }
```

I am trying to access the 6th argument in COMMAND_TRANSFER_BASE64 case above from args, but there isn't a specific type to receive a function. Is there any work around? This is the getBase64 Method for reference -

```
public void getBase64(String format, boolean transparent, boolean includeImage, boolean includeText, boolean cropToImageSize, Callback callback) {
        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        Bitmap bitmap = createImage(format.equals("png") && transparent, includeImage, includeText, cropToImageSize);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(
            format.equals("png") ? Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG : Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
            format.equals("png") ? 100 : 90,
            byteArrayOS);
        callback.invoke(null, Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
```

I have tried most of the provided methods but no luck.